# Counter within a if-statement will not print whats needed

Tags: c

I'm working to create a set of values below a 1000 and then subset them according to number size, and then count how many are in set.  The counter part will not print a statement.  Thanks for the help in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int n;
int arraySize;
int randN;
int rand();

int countOne = 0;
int countTwo = 0;
int countThree = 0;
int countFour = 0;
int countFive = 0;


int main()
{
    printf("What is the size of the array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int array[n];
    int i;

    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {   
            randN=rand() % 999;
            array[i]=randN;
    }   

    for (i = 0 ; i < n; i++ )
    {   
        printf("%i\n", array[i]);
    }   
//The issue starts below here 
    if(0>=array[i] && array[i] <= 199){
        for(i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){
         countOne++;
         printf("%d", countOne);
         }   
       }   
}
```

Comment: Your problem is at `0>=array[i]`. That will never be true.

Comment: I tried array[i] >= 0 and am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: I'm aiming for if array[i] is greater then or equal to 0 and array[i] is less then or equal to 199 then add countOne

Comment: When you reach the `if (0 <= array[i] && array[i] <= 199)`, the value of `i` is equal to `n` (since it is after the for-loop above). Therefore, the value of `array[i]` will be undefined.

Comment: @charlierproctor thanks, I added some pointer assortment and got it working.

Comment: So, @charlierproctor, what would be the answer? Get the comparison right an move the if-for-print into the loop?